# Define function in leaflet cluster options

Tags: r, leaflet

How do I custom the cluster options so that the markers aren't clustered by the default Leaflet markerOptions(count of markers), but by a function (mean, maximum or whatelse) that I choose?
For Java i could find tons of examples, but for R I couldn't find anything.
Only thing I could find is something that has to do with 
"iconCreateFunction" and "JS()", but I don't know if it's right and how it works..

```
leaflet(data) %>%
addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(lng=data$lon, lat=data$lat, clusterOptions = list(iconCreateFunction = JS(...
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a bit of your example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replying to old question however some users still may find this useful.
You need to pass custom `iconCreateFunction` javascript formula to `markerClusterOptions()` 
The main challenge is how you pass data to the markers so that you can apply a formula to data which are in the cluster of markers. I have tried to read the javascript code which is on the example website, but since I don't know js I could only find a workaround.
Example website: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html
The user is adding data into `marker[i].number` in `populate()` function.
If anyone knows how this work please add your solution which I assume will be better than what I currently use.

My workaround is to store data into `addMarkers(... , title=myData, ...)` or `addCircleMarkers(... , weight=myData , ...)`

```
library(leaflet)
# sample data to pass to markers
myData <- sample(x=1:1000, size=1000, replace=TRUE)
# add some NaN which may occur in real data
myData[sample(x=1:1000, size=100, replace=FALSE)] <- NaN
circle.colors <- sample(x=c("red","green","gold"),size=1000,replace=TRUE)

avg.formula = 
"function (cluster) {
var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;
var avg = 0;
var mFormat = ' marker-cluster-';
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
if(markers[i].options.weight != undefined){
sum += markers[i].options.weight;
count += 1;
}
}
avg = Math.round(sum/count);
if(avg<333) {mFormat+='small'} else if (avg>667){mFormat+='large'}else{mFormat+='medium'};
return L.divIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + avg + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster'+mFormat, iconSize: L.point(40, 40) });
}"

# in the above we loop through every marker in cluster access the options.weight
# which is our data, if data is not undefined (not NA or NaN) then we sum data
# and count occurrence
# at the end of code we check if average is more/less to assign default
# marker icons marker-cluster-small marker-cluster-medium marker-cluster-large
# for green yellow red respectively

# stroke = FALSE is a must if you store data in weights !!!
leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
 addCircleMarkers(lng=~long,lat=~lat,radius=10,stroke=FALSE,fillOpacity=0.9,
                   fillColor = circle.colors,weight=myData,
                   popup=as.character(myData),
                   clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(avg.formula)))
```

for any other custom formula you need to adjust

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
if(markers[i].options.weight != undefined){
sum += markers[i].options.weight;
count += 1;
}
}
```

Kind regards,
Peter