# R Leaflet - Adapt cluster marker to display function result

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, markerclusterer

Question similar to @U.Cremona's ([Define function in leaflet cluster options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605681/define-function-in-leaflet-cluster-options/34164952#34164952)) but with reproducible data.

Using leaflet in R, how can we have the cluster marker show the result of a function instead of the default count of markers.

 For example, using the data below, the cluster would show the `mean()` of `data$julian` for the points located within the cluster's reach, or count how many different `ID` are within the cluster reach.

```
  data<- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1434160835, 1434160836,1434160837, 1434160853, 1434166213, 
                                      1434166216, 1434166218, 1434166237,1434171611, 1434171635), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
               lon = c(-119.8777, -119.9614, -119.8769, -119.8775, -120.2283, 
                       -120.2285, -119.8429, -120.0954, -120.3957, -120.4421), 
               lat = c(34.4041,34.376, 34.4061, 34.4021, 34.4696, 
                       34.4697, 34.1909, 34.4328, 34.4554, 34.4456), 
               ID = c("Z11","Z05","Z01", "Z04", "Z11", "Z04","Z01","Z05","Z05","Z11"),
               julian = c(16599.0837384259, 16599.08375, 16599.0837615741, 16599.0839467593, 16599.1459837963, 
                          16599.1460185185,16599.1460416667, 16599.1462615741, 16599.2084606481, 16599.2087384259)), 
          .Names = c("timestamp", "lon", "lat", "ID","julian"),
          row.names = c(1:10), 
          class = "data.frame")
data$ID<-as.factor(data$ID)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you can but I would be quite happy if someone could prove me wrong!